# How do I find the maximum and the average for 3 weights (pounds,ounces) I have a program that compares weights

Tags: java, oop, average

I need help figuring out how to find the average and the maximum weight. Down below you will see the methods templates I have created; However, I can't figure out how to find the max and average weight.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Weight weight1 = new Weight(4, 13);
    Weight weight2 = new Weight(4, 1);
    Weight weight3 = new Weight(14, 10); // 14 lbs 10 ounces

    System.out.println(weight1 + ", " + weight2 + ", " + weight3);
    System.out.println("Minimum: " + findMinimum(weight1, weight2, weight3));
    System.out.println("Average: " + findAverage(weight1, weight2, weight3));    
}

private static Weight findMinimum(Weight weight1, Weight weight2, Weight weight3) {
    if(weight1.lessThan(weight2)) {
        if (weight1.lessThan(weight3)) {
            return weight1;
        }
        else {
            return weight3;
        }
    }
    else {
        if(weight2.lessThan(weight3)) {
            return weight2;
        }
        else {
            return weight3;
        }
    }
}

private static Weight findMaximum(Weight weight1, Weight weight2, Weight weight3) {
    
}
    
private static Weight findAverage(Weight weight1, Weight weight2, Weight weight3){
    Weight results=new Weight(0,0);
    results= +weight1;
}
```

Comment: `findMaximum()` should be very similar to your existing `findMinimum()`, just working in the other direction. For the average, though, what do you have available to you in the `Weight` class to retrieve the weight that it represents? That class obviously has a `toString()` method. What else does it have?...maybe a `getWeight()` method?

Answer (score 0):

For min and max, first create a function that compares Weight:

```
public class WeightComparator implements Comparator<Weight> {
    int compare(Weight w1, Weight w2) {
        // return -1 if w1 is higher
        // return 0 if they are equal
        // return 1 if w2 is higher
    }
}
```

With that you can start sorting your weights. For example, put them in a collection and use sort:

```
ArrayList<Weight> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new Weight(...));
list.add(new Weight(...));
list.add(new Weight(...));
Collections.sort(list, new WeightComparator());
```

Once done, the min is the first element, the max the last element of your list.

For the average, just sum up all the elements, then divide by their count.

```
public Weight getAverage(List<Weight> list) {
    int pounds = 0;
    int ounces = 0;

    for (Weight w: list) {
        pounds += w.getPounds();
        ounces += w.getOunces();
    }

    return new Weight(pounds / list.size(), ounces / list.size);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your logic should simply be:

```
findMaximum(w1, w2, w3) {
    if (w1 > w2 and w1 > w3) {
        return w1
    }
    if (w2 > w1 and w2 > w3) {
        return w2
    }
    if (w3 > w1 and w3 > w2) {
        return w3
    }
}


findAverage(w1, w2, w3) {
    return (w1+w2+w3) / 3
}
```